# jogl display calling just one time

Tags: jogl

I have question. I try to learn OpenGL, in particular JOGL. Can you tell is it possible to call the function display() just once without permanent looping. Rendering takes a lot of power because the function is called permanently. thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [GLAutoDrawable.display()](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/javax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable.html#display%28%29) just once, do it on the good thread (especially if you use an AWT GLCanvas or a Swing GLJPanel). If you need to do that several times, rather create your own animator by using GLAnimatorControl or put some code directly into GLEventListener.display(GLAutoDrawable) and use Animator or FPSAnimator.

P.S: [The official JogAmp forum](http://forum.jogamp.org) is a better place to get some advices on JOGL, JOAL and JOCL.